# How to undelete files and folders that have been deleted using shift+delete

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, undelete

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I mistakenly shift+deleted files and folders in my Documents folder. I'm trying to use **extundelete** utility but which is not helping me.

I don't know which sda* to be used. Please help me out with this.

```
$ sudo extundelete --restore-all --after $(date -d "-2 hours" +%s) /dev/sda
```

which shows the following output:

```
Only show and process deleted entries if they are deleted on or after 1521022350 and before 9223372036854775807.

extundelete: Bad magic number in super-block when trying to open filesystem /dev/sda
```

When I do

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

it shows the following:

[image: screenshot]

Please help me out how to recover data using extundelete

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copying the text here and using code formatting is best.

Answer (score 2):

`sda` is the whole drive, you should use `sda5` as this appears to be your OS-partition. So if you modify your command to

```
sudo extundelete --restore-all --after $(date -d "-2 hours" +%s) /dev/sda5
```

it should work as you expect.

Comment: I tried that one too, it shows the same error `Bad magic number in super-block when trying to open filesystem /dev/sda5`

Comment: @php12345, this error happens with the basic tool `fsck`. Here is an answer for that. It didn't work for me. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456772/ext2fs-open2-bad-magic-number-in-super-block

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use `extundelete` on a mounted partition. Rather, you should use a Ubuntu Live DVD or USB to boot, install extundelete in the live system, and then use it on the unmounted `/dev/sda5` partition.

You'll also need some other media (another USB stick will do) to restore those deleted files to.

This guide should walk you through it: [The Magic of Extundelete](http://edunham.net/2015/03/02/the_magic_of_extundelete.html)

Comment: Mine is unmounted, and its giving me this error.